# Transferring large arrays to the client

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, web-services

I need to transfer a large array of 16 bit integers to a client using an AJAX request to a web service.  This array is essentially grey-scale pixel data for an image with some additional meta data.

The original image is in a proprietary format that is not supported by browsers.  A typical image is 2000px x 4000px so the array could contain 8,000,000+ 16bit values.

Is it acceptable to make one AJAX request and return this entire array in one response or should I split into into smaller chunks and request each individually?  If it is an accepted practice to transfer the whole array in one response, would I have to handle unreliable connections during the request (or does that come 'out of the box' in the browsers)?

We are writing both the client and the web service so we are entirely flexible on our approach.

Comment: as far as I know it is always better to keep the amount of requests as low as possible and fetch as much data as possible in one request. That is because an http request itself takes time even if just headers are sent. If a connection problem occurs you can handle it via javascript...

Comment: Hm, sending large packages (100K each) is probably not a bad idea, but you should send it in something very close to binary.  If you only need the data to show an image you should convert it to a image on the server.  But it depends on the network.

Comment: The browsers you have to support, do they all support websockets and typed arrays? Because that's probably the best way to do this sort of thing in JavaScript

Comment: @Joni Unfortunately the browsers we are likely to deploy on will be slightly behind the curve (the users will usually be managed by some form of corporate IT so are not free to upgrade).  +1 though because I didn't know about typed arrays until your post, and it's definitely something worth exploring.

Comment: why do you need 16bit values to represent grayscale data? shouldn't 8bit suffice?

Comment: You may want to compress that.. http://www.dclunie.com/papers/spie_mi_2000_compression.pdf

Comment: What do you want to do with that data after it's received? Processing 16MB of anything with a subpar JavaScript interpreter is going to be slow no matter how you transfer it...

Comment: @lostsource Unfortunately we need 16bit greyscale. We can't loose any resolution in the dark areas as it is critical to the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you need to transfer is more than 16 MB in size, but you should get a smaller size by using gzip given the fact that you're working with unarchived data. Also you should think about a very fast serialization format (because you will need a lot of processing both on the client and the server to serialize/deserialize the data).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to GZIP, I will check it out. It looks like I will have to compress it using something like that and send if all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have mentioned, if you enable gzip compressed transfer in the server, the browser should decompress the image automatically. If the image is a scanned document with large areas of the same color this can actually compress the image quite a bit; if it's more like an aerial photograph then not so much.

Now that you have the image on the client side you have another problem: what to do with those 8 million 16-bit pixels.

Before we had typed arrays we had to use strings to represent arbitrary data. This is safer than it sounds because in JavaScript strings are sequences of 16-bit code units that *may* be interpreted as text encoded in UTF-16. JavaScript has no problem at all with strings with invalid encoding.

This means you can store your image as one long string, and access the individual pixels using `charCodeAt`. This should be reasonably fast for most manipulation purposes.

Here's an example of loading 16-bit binary data (actually a PNG icon) into a string and outputting the first 16 elements:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
    success: function(data) {
        // Now we have the data, let's show it:
        var out = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            out += ","+data.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
        }
        console.log(out.substring(1));
    },
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=utf-16be");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("ERROR: "+textStatus+" "+errorThrown);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    },
})
```

(Live example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7D9U/2/))

Comment: Fantastic thank you, I didn't know it was that easy. I can send the UTF-16 encoded image to the client in JSON (or something better) and parse it really easily using charCodeAt.